# makefile tilde expansion, difference between windowsXP and windows7

Tags: windows, makefile

I am recompiling a project. Previously I was using WindowsXP, but I switched to Windows7.

Problematic part of the makefile is:

```
%else
        INSTALL_DIR := C:\PROGRA~1\micros~1.0\VC
%endif

%if !%exists($(INSTALL_DIR))
%error blablabla...
%endif
```

It seems, that `PROGRA~1` is already expanded in the first line, because I am getting following error:

```
(line 25): Test: ')' expected; got "Files". Stop.
```

Why the behaviour is different than under WindowsXP? How to cope with it? (It is not the only place where I use such construction...)

---

Maximus - thank you for your answer - it helped me a lot ;) I wanted to make sure that everything is OK, and I noticed, that I made stupid mistake.

Once again, more code:

```
%ifdef OMAKE_MSVC_INSTALL_DIR
    INSTALL_DIR := $(OMAKE_MSVC_INSTALL_DIR)
%echo case 1
%echo $(INSTALL_DIR)
%else
    INSTALL_DIR := C:\PROGRA~1\micros~1.0\VC
    %echo case 2
%endif

%if !%exists($(INSTALL_DIR))
    %error blablabla
%endif
```

I thought, that case 2 is executed, but in fact case 1 is executed...
Now everything is clear :)
Thanks :-)

Comment: Does these short names **really** exists on problem PC? May be your path has different short names variant. Anyway - it's a bad idea to use hardcoded shortnames, they are not constant.

Comment: Yes, I checked with "dir /x". Unfortunately, that is not the case...

Comment: 1. Are you sure that "%else" block is executed? (INSTALL_DIR := C:\PROGRA~1\micros~1.0\VC), may be condition (not visible here) failed?  2. What versions of compilers you are using in XP and 7?